# IBM Informix MacOS v-ids.12.10.FC9DE - Unrecognized Options

Tags: informix

I would like to install the latest IBM Informix on my local Mac but whenever I am trying to run the installer I am facing the following issue.

```
Preparing to install...
Extracting the installation resources from the installer archive...
Configuring the installer for this system's environment...

Launching installer...

Unrecognized option: -d64
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I am using Hotspot JDK 8 after giving up on JDK 11.xx.

Has anyone encountered the issue before. Please share your experience and if anyone has any thoughts.

Comment: Configuration question. Ensure you are using a supported combination of versions (operating-system, Informix version), as per the technote here https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27013343#mac  , and if you are not using one of these supported combinations you might need to wait...

Comment: Which version of macOS are you running on?  And are you working with a `.dmg` file or with the `.tar` file (no `.dmg` in the name) which you extract and then run `./ids_install`?

Comment: I downloaded a copy of 12.10.FC9DE in a tar file onto a machine running macOS 10.14.6 Mojave and, as root, ran `./ids_install` and got past the point where you got "`Unrecognized option: -d64`".  Running `java -version` reveals `java version "1.8.0_192"` —
`Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_192-b12)` —
`Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.192-b12, mixed mode)`.